# How can I power this LED Matrix?

Tags: arduino, led, wiring, led-matrix

I'm controlling a 16x32 LED matrix with an Arduino and have it wired correctly (I think) but I'm having trouble with the power. I tried to follow [the instructions from Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix/powering) but was unsuccessful in that they described parts (and claimed to include others) that I don't have.

[Here is an Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUpZf.jpg) that I threw together of what I have. The first is the LED matrix and the other two are parts that I have that may be applicable to this solution. (The power supply is +5V 2A, as recommended by Adafruit).

I think I have the pieces of the puzzle, I just need help wiring them up and making things work without frying my matrix or Arduino.

P.S. I couldn't use a Molex connection from a power supply unit for a desktop, could I? This will end up being very close to a computer.

Comment: Please post the circuit that you used.

Comment: Circuit for the power? Or circuit for the control to the Arduino? I have done nothing with the power so far. As far as the wiring to the Arduino goes, here's the link to the instructions I used, no schematic, sorry:

https://learn.adafruit.com/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix/wiring-the-16x32-matrix

Answer (score 1):

I assume that that the cable shown in your second picture will plug into the white connector on the back of your LED matrix.  If so, I would cut off one connector, and connect the two red wires to the positive terminal of the barrel connector-to-terminal block adapter, and the two black wires to the negative terminal of that terminal block.

Comment: Yes, the two cables do match up nicely. I was thinking about doing exactly that, but wasn't sure about the gauge of the wires. Should that be of concern? Or is it not enough juice running through them to worry?

Comment: If the cable was supplied with the display, I'd assume that the wire gauge was adequate.

Comment: The wire gauge is of concern if you have several feet/meters of it.